# How to show the categoried column values if user click to sort the view

Tags: sorting, view, xpages

I have a view panel displaying a categorized view, all my columns are sortable.
When I click to sort one of the not categorized columns the values in categorized columns are not displayed. this is normal behaviour for a sorted categorized view in IBMNotes client as well.

The problem is that I need the category values to display if the view is sorted (clicked on sort icon) or display another column containing the category values, but only if the view is sorted.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

First option: use more views with different sort setting in columns after category column. Dynamically change the view name. This works as you want, but it has performance impact on server and I don't recommend it.

Second option: use hide when on redundant (flat) column based on sort options. Exact formula depends on your implementation (submit page code).

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to hide a column based on sort option?